# VM servers running slow but task manager showing everything good

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

I have several VMware VMs running on Win Server 2008, which often encounter slowness from time to time. Most of the time it's during the busy month end activities. Weirdly, I find it hard to explain the root cause for this problem as everytime users complain of the slowness, I go into the server and launch resource monitor but didn't find anything wrong with the CPU & memory load, disk IO also looks decent. What else could be the problem?

There's several other VMs running on the same exsi host but only this few facing the problem. Any idea how I can monitor from VMware point of view through vCenter?

Comment: Did you go into the VMs themselves and check the resource usage and the Event Viewer?

Comment: Install and run this on a machine that isn't hosted in your virtual infrastructure. Connect it to your virtual infrastructure. It will show you where your performance problems are - https://www.veeam.com/virtual-server-management-one-free.html